# Check if number is divisible by another number in JS

Tags: javascript, puzzle

I am pretty new at this stuff, and I am solving a series of questions, but I've got lost in this one.

I have to verify if a number can be divided by other, and the answer must be true or false.

I got his

```
function solucao(numero, x) {
    
    solucao(numero % x); 
    
    if (solucao === 0)  {
        resultado = true;
        
    }else{
        resultado = false;
    }
            
}
```

But I'm getting runtime error and can't see whats is missing.

Comment: What is the error? please share the error

Comment: What's the error if I may ask?

Comment: You are calling a function within itself - this is called recursion. I don't understand why you need to do this. Using the % operator as you have done should to tell you whether the number is divisible by the other number. Then get your function to return a result - return ...

Comment: All you have to do  inside your function is `return !(numero % x);` It is that simple, nothing else is required. The reason this works is because `0` is a "falsy" value while any other number is a "truthy" value.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to check if a number `numero` is divisible by `x`. The modulo operator can help. Try this:

```
function solucao(numero, x){
    if (numero % x == 0){
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function solucao(numero, x) {
    
    let resultado;
    
    if (numero % x === 0)  {
        resultado = true;
        
    }else{
        resultado = false;
    }
            return resultado;
}
```

I think you get confused at some point. You are calling the function, inside of itself. You should do like this, and also, declare the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this will help:

```js
    function checkIfDivided(){
// in this section the variables come from an html document
            var number=parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
             var divisor=parseInt(document.getElementById("divisor").value);
            if(number%divisor==0)
              return true;
            else return false;
    }


or



    function checkIfDivided(number,divisor){
//in the function the variable are given as parameters
            if(number%divisor==0)
              return true;
            else return false;

    }
```

Comment: Ohhh sorry my mistake,i wrote an answer with html so I used the document.getElementById. But turns out he did not need the html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two things to me:

1. You haven't declared your 'resultado' variable ( this can be as simple as just typing 'let resultado;' without the single quotes
2. You haven't returned your 'resultado' variable after the if/else statement

Right now, your function is using an undeclared variable and not returning anything, so that is why you are getting an error. Fix the two above steps and you should be good! :)

Comment: You didn't address the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly understand that the modulus operator is the way to go. Using it we discover that `12` is divisible by `3` because `12 % 3` return zero. Zero is considered a "falsy" value while any other number is considered "truthy".

Given this then if `12 % 3` returns a "falsey" value (zero) we can't use the result directly. But what if we can "flip" false to true? We can, using the `not` operator (`!`).

Using the `!` operator on the *result* of a math problem requires the use of parentheses around the math problem itself.

So the problem in code becomes `(12 % 3)` and to 'flip' it with the `!` operator it becomes

`!(12 % 3)`.

This is proven below with:

1. `console.log(!(12 % 3))` --> logs true
2. `console.log(!(12 % 5))` --> logs false

The function implementation of that is simple and also proven:

1. `console.log(isDivisible(12,3));` --> logs true
2. `console.log(isDivisible(12,5));` --> logs false

```js
console.log(!(12 % 3))
console.log(!(12 % 5))

function isDivisible(number, x){
 return !(number % x);
}
 
console.log(isDivisible(12,3));
console.log(isDivisible(12,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way to do so and i think its much cleaner.

```
console.log(Number.isInteger(10/2)) //true
console.log(Number.isInteger(4/2)) // false

//a must be greater than b
function check(a,b) {
 console.log(Number.isInteger(a/b))
 return Number.isInteger(a/b)
}

check(10,5)//true
check(8,3)//false
```

Answer (score 0):

The error came because of the recursion coming from line `solucao(numero % x);`. Since you already used the variable name "solucao", you could try assigning the modulus operation result to a different variable, for example: `const solution = numero % x`. Next, we should declare variable resultado that could look like this:

```
let resultado;
// continue with your code
if (solution === 0) {
    resultado = true;
} else {
    resultado = false;
}
```

After that you also need to return the value of resultado, for example like that: `return resultado;`

Your full code could look like that:

```
function solucao(numero, x) {
    const solution = numero % x; 
    let resultado;
    if (solution === 0)  {
        resultado = true;
    } else {
        resultado = false;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Since the operation of modulus if a number is divisible returns 0, you could also return a shorter version that only checks if the result equals 0:

```
function solucao(numero, x) {
    return numero % x === 0
}
```